# Limit Catalog Price rules?

Tags: catalog-price-rules

Is the number of Catalog Price rules limited? Would 5000 be a problem?

I am trying to figure out a way to implement price rules. 
Customers get a discount on a single article or on a group of articles. Either because of the customer group they are in, or an individual agreement.As Magento only supports pricerules per group, I wanted to treat a customer (a company) as a group as well.

Any thoughts highly appreciated.

---

**The actual problem:**

We are a wholesale company in lighting. 
**What I need to implement:**
After login, the customer needs to see his own personal prices. 
And of course, these price rules need to be updated regularly.

The customer can place an order via the site, but as most configurations are complex, and need customising, we always consult the customer. And the actual order and invoicing is always done via a separate erp system.

**We have 4 files with price rules (generated from another system):**

1. customerID - article(1500st)
2. customerID - articlegroup (75st)
3. customergroup - article (3000st)
4. customergroup - article-group (500st)

*NB: I have placed the customer groups in a customer group category, so I could use it in the catalog price rules.*

**To determine the individual price:**

1. If article in file 1 -> done. If not goto 2.
2. If articlegroup in file 2 -> done. If not goto 3.
3. If article in file 3 -> done. If not goto 4.
4. Articlegroup is in file 4. Done.

Perhaps an extension that would work?
Also willing to pay someone for this.
Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you put 5,000 catalog price rules in your Magento site then you are going to have performance issues.  If the answer to your problem is to make 5,000 price rules then you most likely need to rethink what you're attempting to accomplish.

What are you trying to do exactly and maybe someone on here can come up with an alternate solution for you.

Comment: I added a more detailed description to my initial question.